# How to display an excerpt from a single post using Jekyll

Tags: html, jekyll

I'm creating a blog site using Jekyll and I want to add a short "about" section on the homepage. Instead of creating a separate paragraph, I'm going to create an "About Me" post (about-me.md) and insert an excerpt from that post on the homepage in its place (beneath it will be a link to read the rest of the article).

The only information I can find online is about the "latest posts" section utilizing the 'for' loop to show the 5 (or more) recent posts. I can't find anything else in the Jekyll documentation that explains how to display an excerpt from one specific post.

I've tried changing

```
{{ post.excerpt }}
```

to

```
{{ about-me.excerpt }}
```

but to no avail.

Below is the 'recent posts' implementation:

```
<div class="about-section">
  <h1>About Me</h1>
  <ul>
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
      {{ post.excerpt }}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

This works to display the recent posts including an excerpt. I need to only display the excerpt from the 'about-me.md' post immediately under the  title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the YML/front matter of your about-me post looks like this:

```
---
title: About me
featured: true
---

The content of your post...
```

And make sure the home page layout looks like this:

```html
<div class="about-section">
  <h1>About Me</h1>
  <ul>
    {% assign featuredposts = site.posts | where:'featured','true' %}
    {% for post in featuredposts limit:1 %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
      {{ post.excerpt }}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```